# Matlab linprog maximization

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, linear-programming

as part of a larger code i need to solve a linear program, I included the part written so far (with dummy numbers) below.
However, I just started using Matlab (used R before that) and ran into the problem, that the linear optimization function linprog, only solves minimization problems. Mine is a maximization problem.

Is there any way to have Matlab calculate a maximization problem (another function, or some obvious trick i am overlooking?)

```
% Clear and clc
clear
clc

X = [  7   7   7
       5   9   7
       4   6   5
       5   9   8
       6   9   5];

Y = [ 4   4
      7   7
      5   7
      6   2
      3   6];

% Get number of DMUs (n), inputs (m) and outputs (s)
[n, m] = size(X);
s = size(Y,2);

% Take logarithms of all values
lnX = log(X);
lnY = log(Y);

%lower bounds for variables (Eta η, xi ξ, outputs,inputs)
lb = [0 0 ones(1,(s+m))];

%Equality constraints
Aeq = [ones(n,1) -ones(n,1) lnY -lnX];
beq = zeros(n,1);

%options to surpress the "different algorithm" warning
options = getDEAoptions(n);
linprogoptions = options.optimopts;

%Initialize weight matrix
geometricDEAWeights = zeros(n,m+s);

%DEA Optimization function
for DMUvalue = 1:n
    f = [1 -1 lnY(DMUvalue,:) -lnX(DMUvalue,:)];
    [z, ~, exitflag, ~, dual] = linprog(f, [], [], Aeq, beq, lb, [],linprogoptions);
    geometricDEAWeights(DMUvalue,:) = z'; 
end
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to turn multiply all values in the objective function with -1, or just call "-f" in the linprog command.

Best seulberg1